# report date range is not working in google analytics core reporting api v4 php library

Tags: php, google-analytics, report

```
 $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
 $dateRange->setStartDate("2017-05-23");
 $dateRange->setEndDate("2017-11-27");
```

Hello guys, I am trying to fetch data from analytics api php library for specified date range.but I am getting the data till the date 2017-06-03.